# Converting from field: value format to CSV

Tags: csv, text-processing, format-conversion

I have a file in the following format (well, sort of):

```
RECORD_SEPARATOR
foo: some foo value
bar: another value
baz: 123
RECORD_SEPARATOR
foo: another foo value
bar: yet another value
baz: 345
RECORD_SEPARATOR
foo: a third foo
RECORD_SEPARATOR
bar: a fourth bar
baz: 111
```

and so on. The key point here is that not all records have all fields present.

My question: What's a super-simple way to convert this data into CSV format? That is, in my example

```
foo,bar,baz
some foo value,another value,123
another foo value,yet another value,345
a third foo,,
,a fourth bar,111
```

Of course you can write a awk (or perl, or Python) script for this, but I'm hoping there's something pre-existing, or some trick to make it a very short script.

Note: I'm looking for something that's Unix-command-line-oriented of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi with the great Miller http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc, starting from

```
foo: some foo value
bar: another value
baz: 123

foo: another foo value
bar: yet another value
baz: 345

foo: a third foo

bar: a fourth bar
baz: 111
```

you can run

```
mlr --x2p --ips ": " --barred cat then unsparsify --fill-with "" inputFile
```

and have this pretty print output

```
+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
| foo               | bar               | baz |
+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
| some foo value    | another value     | 123 |
| another foo value | yet another value | 345 |
| a third foo       | -                 | -   |
| -                 | a fourth bar      | 111 |
+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
```

If you want a CSV, run

```
mlr --x2c --ips ": " cat then unsparsify --fill-with "" inputFile
```

and you will have

```
foo,bar,baz
some foo value,another value,123
another foo value,yet another value,345
a third foo,,
,a fourth bar,111
```

Comment: Using mlr version 4.5.0, and trying your second command-line, I get: `mlr: option "--x2c" not recognized`

Comment: @einpoklum please try with the 5.4 compiled version https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/releases/tag/5.4.0 or with `mlr --ixtab --ips ": " --ocsv cat then unsparsify --fill-with "" inputFile`

Comment: Well, 5.4.0 has [issues building](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/issues/221)... and with this new command line I get: `mlr: verb "unsparsify" not found. Please use "mlr --help" for a list.`

Comment: @einpoklum you could use the already compiled version https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/releases/download/5.4.0/mlr.linux.x86_64